# Need Sql Query to generate output as shown below tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Here in this example three tables are used Employee, EmployeeWork and EmployeeEducation.

Employee table has two data rows.

Employee has six data rows, three for first employee and other three for second employee.

Finally EmployeeEducation has four data row, two for first employee and two for next employee.

I want output (if possible or alternative solution ) as shown in last table Output Sample.

```
Employee
+--------------------------+
|empId | empName | empPhone|
+--------------------------+
|1     | John    | 1234    |
|2     | Rick    | 5678    |
+--------------------------+

EmployeeWork
+--------------------------------------------+
|empWrkId | empId | DepartmentName | WorkYrs |
+--------------------------------------------+
|1        | 1     | Support        | 2       |
|2        | 1     | Development    | 3       |
|3        | 1     | Retail         | 5       |
+--------------------------------------------+
|4        | 2     | Support        | 1       |
|5        | 2     | Development    | 3       |
|6        | 2     | Retail         | 6       | 
+--------------------------------------------+

EmployeeEducation
+-----------------------------------------+
|empEduId | empId | EduName | Division    |
+-----------------------------------------+
|1        | 1     | Inter   | First       |
|2        | 1     | Bachelor| Second      |
+-----------------------------------------+
|3        | 2     | Bachelor| First       |
|4        | 2     | Masters | Distinction |
+-----------------------------------------+

What can we do to get the output as below combining above three tables?

Output Sample
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| empId | empName | DepartmentName | WorkYrs | EduName | Division    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1     | John    | Support        | 2       | Inter   | First       |
| 1     | John    | Development    | 3       | Bachelor| Second      |
| 1     | John    | Retail         | 5       | NULL    | NULL        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2     | Rick    | Support        | 1       | Bachelor| First       |
| 2     | Rick    | Development    | 3       | Masters | Distinction |
| 2     | Rick    | Retail         | 6       | NULL    | NULL        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Join the three tables, with empID and output the required columns

Comment: I don't understand how (for instance) 'Inter' relates to 'Support' as opposed to 'Development' or 'Retail'

Comment: Does empEduId match to empWrkId else once CANNOT get the desired output. For example why would EduName and Division for John be NULL

Comment: Also, you seem unclear about which RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no actual relation between education and work, you need to create one, which from your sample output it appears as though you are simply ordering by ID, so for each table you can apply `ROW_NUMBER()` to get a field to join on:

```
/******************************************************************************************
GENERATE TABLES AND SAMPLE DATA
******************************************************************************************/
DECLARE @Employee TABLE (empId INT, empName VARCHAR(50), empPhone INT);
INSERT @Employee VALUES (1, 'John', 1234), (2, 'Rick', 5678);

DECLARE @EmployeeWork TABLE (empWrkId INT, empId INT, DepartmentName VARCHAR(50), WorkYrs INT);
INSERT @EmployeeWork
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 'Support', 2), (2, 1, 'Development', 3), (3, 1, 'Retail', 5), 
    (4, 2, 'Support', 1), (5, 2, 'Development', 3), (6, 2, 'Retail', 6)


DECLARE @EmployeeEducation TABLE (empEduId INT, empId INT, EduName VARCHAR(50), Division VARCHAR(50));
INSERT @EmployeeEducation
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Inter', 'First'), (2, 1, 'Bachelor', 'Second'),
    (3, 2, 'Bachelor', 'First'), (4, 2, 'Masters', 'Distinction');


/******************************************************************************************
ACTUAL QUERY
******************************************************************************************/
WITH EmpEd AS
(   SELECT  EmpID,
            EduName,
            Division,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY empID ORDER BY empEduID)
    FROM    @EmployeeEducation
), EmpWork AS
(   SELECT  EmpID,
            DepartmentName,
            WorkYrs,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY empID ORDER BY empWrkId)
    FROM    @EmployeeWork
)
SELECT  e.EmpID,
        e.EmpName,
        ee.DepartmentName,
        ee.WorkYrs,
        ee.EduName,
        ee.Division,
        ee.RowNumber,
        EmpName2 = CASE WHEN ee.RowNumber = 1 THEN e.EmpName ELSE '-' END
FROM    @Employee AS e
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  EmpID = ISNULL(w.EmpID, e.EmpID),
                    RowNumber = ISNULL(w.RowNumber, e.RowNumber),
                    w.DepartmentName,
                    w.WorkYrs,
                    e.EduName,
                    e.Division
            FROM    EmpWork AS w
                    FULL JOIN EmpEd AS e
                        ON e.EmpID = w.EmpID
                        AND e.RowNumber = w.RowNumber
        ) AS ee
            ON ee.EmpID = e.EmpID
ORDER BY e.EmpID;
```

I have left `EduName` as `NULL` where there is no match, changing null values for `-` is probably a job best left to the presentation layer, similarly I have left `empID` and `EmpName` repeating in each row, as choosing whether or not to display this should again be a job for the presentation layer, I have however included a column at the end `EmpName2` which shows how you could use the `RowNumber` column to determine whether or not to display the column name.

Answer (score 0):

I think these SQL useful to you.

```
select ew.empId , e.empName , ew.DepartmentName , ew.WorkYrs , ee.EduName , ee.Division     
from Employee e, EmployeeWork ew, EmployeeEducation ee where
e.empId= ew.empId and e.empId= ee.empId
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not convinced that using a JOIN style that was effectively deprecated in 1995 is useful to anyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can also wirte like this:

```
select a.empId,a.empName,a.DepartmentName,a.WorkYrs,b.EduName,b.Division from (
select e.empId,e.empName,
w.DepartmentName,w.WorkYrs,w.empWrkId
from employee e 
left join EmployeeWork w on e.empId = w.empId) a 
left join (
select em.EduName,em.Division,en.empWrkId from EmployeeEducation  em left join EmployeeWork en on em.empId = en.empID
group by en.empId) b on a.empWrkId = b.empWrkId
```

Comment: I tried with above query. It will not generate the required output. Can you please try at your end.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ew.empId, e.empName, ew.DepartmentName, 
       ew.WorkYrs, ee.EduName, ee.Division
FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN EmployeeWork ON e.empId= ew.empId
LEFT JOIN EmployeeEducation ON e.empId= ee.empId
GROUP BY e.empId
```

Comment: I tried with above query. It will not generate the required output. Can you please try at your end.

Comment: Perhaps give an explanation of what the query is try to achieve. I imagine the table names will need to be expanded out on the actual DB. e -> Employee, ew -> EmployeeWork

Answer (score 0):

you can combine join with left join to get this result 
check this query -after checking column names-

```
   select e.empId as id , e.empName ,  ew.DepartmentName , ew.WorkYrs  , edu.EduName , edu.Division
 from employee e
join EmployeeWork ew on ew.empId  = id
left join EmployeeEducation edu on edu.empEduId = empEduId
```